# Ingest CSV file into Data bases using Google Data Fusion

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-data-fusion

im new into Google data fusion, and I can easily upload csv files into big query,
but now I want to upload them into MySQL and Postgres, and I been having failed status when I try to connect even though the connection is validated if I put the table name with ${}

Errors
Exception while trying to validate schema of database table 'Bio_Stats' for connection 'jdbc:mysql://---------.com:3306/GCP1'.

perhaps Im having a problem within the plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Cloud Data Fusion instance a private instance? If so, you might need to set up VPC Peering and CloudSQL proxy to be able to access CloudSQL instances. See [How to connect Data Fusion to Cloud SQL Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235351/how-to-connect-data-fusion-to-cloud-sql-proxy) for more information.